# Reverse personification

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device, personification

Personification is an object or a thing described with a human-like aspect (eg. *The Sun smiled at me*).

Can personification also be used to describe a human with an aspect from an object? For example, in *Oliver Twist*, Dickens says "[Oliver] was badged and ticketed," which describes/compares him with a package or box. Is this a usage of personification or a different type of literary device?

Comment: V.nice question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it is a specific 'literary device', but in general when a person is depicted or treated like an object it is called **objectification.**

> Definition of objectify for English Language Learners
> : to treat (someone) as an object rather than as a person
> (...) -- objectification [noun]
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectify

Example:

> Officials branded people with a label and filed them under a category. They were written up, numbered and 'put up for necessary action.' The applicants for social support resented such unfeeling **objectification**.

Please note that 'objectification' is often used not neutrally, but to express disapproval of treating people like objects.

> It is not good of social work agencies to **objectify** the people they are supposed to help as 'subjects',  'projects' or 'cases.'
>
> The Women's League strongly protested the **objectification** of women in the visual media.

Comment: A reverse search for 'objectification' shows that this answer was given years ago. Much easier than OP trawling through 200+ hits for 'personification'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Except that OP wouldn't know what to search for... but it does strike me now that whenever I am ready with an answer to such a Q, *I ought to first search whether the answer has already been given in the context of a very similar question.* **I shall attempt to identify and mark duplicates in future.** I just didn't expect OP's rather unusual Q to have been asked exactly the same way many years ago by another member!